# Editable Install and Setup.py not Working as Expected

Tags: python, python-packaging

I typically use poetry so i don't have this problem but i am on a project that uses a setup.py to install the package such that absolute imports can be used throughout the source code, but for some reason with the current setup, i need to do `pip install -e .` after each code change for it to take effect. How can I make it permanent so it picks up all source code changes?

Current setup.py looks like:

```
import setuptools


setuptools.setup(
    name='GT Day Of Pipeline',
    version='0.1.1',
    url='https://github.com/Giving-Tuesday/gt-etls/tree/master/day_of',
    description='Package for ingesting and cleaning raw donations from providers from GivingTuesday',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wihthout seeing your file structure and assuming your code is all in a `src` directory, It looks like you aren't including all of the necessary information for package discovery.
Check out [the documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html?highlight=find_packages#package-data) and the [example on including packages in the src directory](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html?highlight=find_packages#finding-simple-packages).

But, adding the following may help:

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(
        where='src',
    ),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Everything is in a `src/` dir, you're right but my find  packages already finds all the packages in `src` as expected.

Comment: And your answer did not solve the problem.

Comment: Then can you maybe include a bit more information about your project. i.e. directory structure, what other config files you have, whether you need any non-python files to be included etc. And, a bit more context on what you mean by "such that absolute imports can be used throughout the source code"